# How to change list item color and text color as per action bar color in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar-compat

I am developing a application where i have to change list item color and text color as per my action bar color how can i achieve this.

ex:-

if action bar color is pink i have to show list item color as black and
   if action bar background is blue i have to shoe list item color as white.

Answer (score 0):

You should store some static variables for the color of the action bar and the color of your list item. Then, in your ListAdapter, for each item, check the color of the action bar and set the background of the list item accordingly.

Comment: thanking you is there any way to use styles and themes

Comment: Yes, you could also define styles for the different colored backgrounds and setStyle() instead.